# Problema com .Include() no Entity Framework(Postgres)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, postgresql

Venho tendo um problema com o EntityFramework, é o seguinte:

Quando uso a string do ORM(.Include) para dar um join em tabelas com chaves estrangeiras, ele automaticamente muda o nome das chaves na string gerada automaticamente por ele e acaba não achando no banco de dados, segue os modelos e a string:

```
[Table("usuarios", Schema = "public")]
public partial class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public Guid nivel_id { get; set; }
    public Guid empresa_id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string senha { get; set; }
    public DateTime datavencimento { get; set; }
    public bool ativo { get; set; }

    public virtual Nivel nivel { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa empresa { get; set; }
```

E no controller eu uso a seguinte string:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var usuarios = db.Usuario
                        .Include(n => n.nivel)
                        .Include(e => e.empresa)
                        .ToList();

        return View(usuarios);
    }
```

Ae no modo debug, o select do EF fica assim, repare no fim da instrução, ele troca o nome nivel_id por nivel_id1, porque isso esta ocorrendo, será que é algum tipo de "conflito" com o provider do Postgres?:

```
SELECT 1 AS "C1", "Extent1"."id", "Extent1"."nivel_id", "Extent1"."empresa_id", "Extent1"."nome", "Extent1"."email", "Extent1"."senha", "Extent1"."datavencimento", "Extent1"."ativo", "Extent2"."id" AS "id1", "Extent2"."nome" AS "nome1", "Extent3"."id" AS "id2", "Extent3"."cnpj", "Extent3"."razaosocial", "Extent3"."nomefantasia", "Extent3"."datafundacao", "Extent3"."contato", "Extent3"."cep", "Extent3"."ibge", "Extent3"."tipologradouro", "Extent3"."logradouro", "Extent3"."numero", "Extent3"."complemento", "Extent3"."bairro", "Extent3"."municipio", "Extent3"."estado", "Extent3"."site", "Extent3"."situacao" FROM "public"."usuarios" AS "Extent1" LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."niveis" AS "Extent2" ON "**Extent1"."nivel_id1" = "Extent2"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "public"."empresas" AS "Extent3" ON "Extent1"."empresa_id1" = "Extent3"."id"
```

Gostaria de saber porque ele faz isso e qual a maneira que tem de corrigir sem que altere o banco de dados ja existente ou o modelo.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço desde já! Vlw

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A maneira elegante de resolver é forçando o atributo [`[ForeignKey]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) no *Model*:

```
[Table("usuarios", Schema = "public")]
public partial class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public Guid nivel_id { get; set; }
    public Guid empresa_id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string senha { get; set; }
    public DateTime datavencimento { get; set; }
    public bool ativo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("nivel_id")]
    public virtual Nivel nivel { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("empresa_id")]
    public virtual Empresa empresa { get; set; }
}
```

Isto acontece porque o nome das suas chaves estrangeiras está um pouco fora da convenção de nomes do Entity Framework, que não usa o "_" (*underline*).

Comment: Pois é velho, o banco de dados, já é existente e um pouco "velho", mas tem que ser esse... Mas muito obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente aqui. E aproveitando a oportunidade, existe alguma lista desse atributos na doc do EF?

Comment: Eu teria que elaborar uma. Pode ser na forma de uma pergunta.

Comment: Ok, farei isso entao. Porem nao seria com tanta urgência, mas ajudaria muito em futuros problemas que com certeza vou ter por causa do meu banco estar fora do padrão da convenção EF. Vlw man!

Comment: Bom, o que precisar, só fazer perguntas. Eu e mais algumas pessoas podemos ir respondendo pra você.